# How to create one form with multiple buttons in the loop

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

It is my form in template,
I am creating multiple forms with two buttons in the loop for voting particular item
and i think it is ugly, how can i avoid that using only one form for all buttons?

```
{% for bill_item in bill_items %}
   <form action="{% url 'bills:change_quantity' bill_item.id %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <button name="up"></button>
      <button name="down"></button>
   </form>
{% endfor %}
```

It is my action in the view

```
def change_quantity(request, bill_item_id):
    bill_item = BillItem.objects.get(pk=bill_item_id)
    if 'up' in request.POST:
        bill_item.increase()
    elif 'down' in request.POST:
        bill_item.decrease()
    bill_item.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/bills/')
```

Answer (score 3):

How about moving bill_item.id to button? Can't test this at the moment, so please treat this as unchecked suggestion

Like:

```
<form action="{% url 'bills:change_quantity' bill_item.id %}" method="post">
{% for x_id,bill_item in enumerate(bill_items) %}
  <button name={% x_id %} value="up"></button>
  <button name={% x_id %} value="down"></button>
```